# How do I execute a bash script while building this rpm package?

Tags: bash, rpm

I want to use my bash script to process a csv file and then put the output csv file into my rpm package.

```
Name:       Test
Version:    1
Release:    1
Summary:    Test
License:    FIXME
Source1:    process.sh
Source2:    test.csv

%description
this is a test build

%build
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/tmp/
install -d -m 755 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp
install -m 755 %{SOURCE1} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/
install -m 755 %{SOURCE2} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/
.$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/process.sh test.csv test_processed.csv

%files
/tmp/test.csv
/tmp/process.sh
```

I've tried many similar iterations of the above code and I can't figure out why it won't run.
I've attempted executing my script in the `%pre` and `%post` sections in rpm but it can't ever find the file.

Answer (score 0):

`%pre` and `%post` happen on the *target* computer when the RPM is installed. You need to copy them to the target root in the `%install` phase for `%files` to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping aside from the non-sense of `/tmp`.

When running:

```
.$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/process.sh test.csv test_processed.csv
```

you are in directory where sources are extraceted. Noth in the %buildroot/tmp.

You should do:

```
...
install -m 755 %{SOURCE2} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/
sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/process.sh test.csv test_processed.csv
install test_processed.csv $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/
```

or

```
...
install -m 755 %{SOURCE2} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/
cd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/
sh process.sh test.csv test_processed.csv
```

The first one, is a best practice.